# Accessibility role imagebutton equivalent in ios

Tags: swift, react-native, uiaccessibility

As we have imagebutton as an accessibility role in react native, I couldn’t find an equivalent to this in iOS. In iOS I could find only button as accessibility trait.

Can we implement the same in iOS for which the button would say imageButton instead of button.
Any help is appreciated.
Update: imagebutton accessibility trait is not present in iOS. iOS has options like
UIAccessibilityTraitImage | UIAccessibilityTraitButton

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the following on your accessibility element:

```
view.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraits(UIAccessibilityTraitImage | UIAccessibilityTraitButton)
```